# Get all numbers starting with 104* including the next line associated with some texts or spaces

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to get all the possible order numbers for example on a given chunk of text. Order number usually starts with 104* and character limit 0f 10. However I was not able to get my desired outcome.

Here is the sample chunk of text.

> 05.12.17 PRZELEW PRZYCHODZACY 05.12.17 1,408.10
>  Referencje : PL0INE117339IZFN
>  Nr Ref: 4339429172
>  Tytuł Płatnosci: 400481
>   1048432317, 400470 104843231
>  6
>  Kontr. : GDANSKDIS SP. Z O.O.
>   UL. OBRONCÓW
>  WYBRZEZA 1 80-398 GDANSK POLAND
>  Nr Banku:
>   18400007 SG Centrala
>  Nr Rachunku: 31184000072413423008101119
>   Data Stempla 171205
>  Kwota Przekazu: 1,408.10 PLN Info Code;
>   0002794237

Some input are like these:

> 05.12.17 PRZELEW PRZYCHODZACY 05.12.17 316,082.18
>  Referencje : PL0INE117339BHBU
>  Nr Ref: 4339079115
>  Tytuł Płatnosci: ID
>   0001817374 ZA1048418311 1
>  0484240771048423894 10484238
>  95AWIZO
>   Z DNIA 05.12.17
>  Kontr. : ZABKA POLSKA SPÓŁKA AKCYJNA
>  PL
>   ANDERSA 7
>  61-894 POZNAN
>  Nr Banku: 12402076 PEKAO Centrum
>   Rozliczeniow
>  Nr Rachunku: 94124017471111001003042253
>  Data
>   Stempla 171205
>  Kwota Przekazu: 316,082.18 PLN

Also like this:

> 05.12.17 PRZELEW PRZYCHODZACY 05.12.17 999,429.47
>  Referencje : PL0INE117339LJBU
>  Nr Ref: 4339548267
>  Tytuł Płatnosci:
>   PY01832649 1048432358 1048432351 10
>  48432466 1048432560 1048432594
>   1048
>  432267 1048432353 1048432450 104843
>  2360 1048432577
>   1048432391/KOR
>  Kontr. : EUROCASH S.A.
>  UL. WISNIOWA 11
>   62-052 KOMORNIKI
>  Nr Banku: 10500028 ING Bank Slaski S.A.
>  Nr
>   Rachunku: 73105000861000002334209315
>  Data Stempla 171205
>  Kwota
>   Przekazu: 999,429.47 PLN
>  Info Code; 0000193176

The code I used is simple as this: `\b104\d*`

My result from the first input was:

> 1048432317

and

> 104843231

The last result was lacking in number as you can see, the last digit was in the next line.

My expected result is a regex that will able to extract all those order numbers without getting cut because the next digit was on the next line or sometimes order number getting cut.

Comment: Remove line breaks first, then extract. E.g. `s.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty)`.

Comment: Sorry not using a code, I just need help with the regular expression itself.

Comment: Without code, you will not be able to do that since no regex can match discontinuous text within one single match operation.

Comment: How about limiting the result to 10 characters?

Comment: No idea what you mean.

Comment: If you can't accept code why did you tag C#? In either case, you need to post the code and regex you have and ask a more specific question. Questions like "can someone do my job for me" are off topic.

Comment: If the line break can come at any point you're forced to write a regex that involves placing a whitespace pattern that handles linebreaks between each digit.

Comment: Thank you for being so rude.

Comment: Here is a pattern that handles line breaks: `1(\r|\n|\r\n)?0(\r|\n|\r\n)?4(?:(\r|\n|\r\n)?\d){7}` but you will get the text *with* the line breaks, there's no way around that unless you remove the line breaks beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex, you can do that with simple string methods and readable LINQ:

```
List<string> orderNumberList = text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "")
  .Split(new char[] { }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  .Where(word => word.StartsWith("104") && word.Length <= 10)
  .ToList();
```

Your sample text blocks contain these 10 numbers:

```
    [0] "1048432358"    
    [1] "1048432351"    
    [2] "1048432466"    
    [3] "1048432560"    
    [4] "1048432594"    
    [5] "1048432267"    
    [6] "1048432353"    
    [7] "1048432450"    
    [8] "1048432360"    
    [9] "1048432577"
```

**Edit**:

> Sorry not using a code, I just need help with the regular expression
>   itself.

Saw this too late. Maybe better provide such informations in the question itself

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you are looking for something like this:

```
string source =
@"05.12.17 PRZELEW PRZYCHODZACY 05.12.17 999,429.47
Referencje : PL0INE117339LJBU
Nr Ref: 4339548267
Tytuł Płatnosci: PY01832649 1048432358 1048432351 10
48432466 1048432560 1048432594 1048
432267 1048432353 1048432450 104843
2360 1048432577 1048432391/KOR
Kontr. : EUROCASH S.A.
UL. WISNIOWA 11
62-052 KOMORNIKI
Nr Banku: 10500028 ING Bank Slaski S.A.
Nr Rachunku: 73105000861000002334209315
Data Stempla 171205
Kwota Przekazu: 999,429.47 PLN
Info Code; 0000193176";

// We have to get rid of new lines and curret returns
var text = source
  .Replace("\r", "")
  .Replace("\n", "");

// pattern: we want 10 digits in total (3 for "104" and 7 for the rest part)
var result = Regex.Matches(text, @"\b104[0-9]{7}")
  .OfType<Match>()
  .Select(match => match.Value)
  .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks, I get the logic now.